# No experience with JS- how to use sweet alert to confirm a form submission?

Tags: javascript, forms, sweetalert

I just found sweet alert and would like to implement it in a simple form confirmation but I am bombarded with information, and I'm trying to understand the JavaScript as I go with no luck.

I want to use the success message [here](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) (third example) but I dont understand how to implement this properly.

I as well would like to have the page refresh after, but I need to tackle this first.

Also, is it possible to use sweet alert to validate a form for empty fields and display an error message?

I understand this is all very rudimentary, I would greatly appreciate some assistance with this as I don't have much of a clue of what I'm doing.

HTML

```
<form id="form" class="topBefore" action="<echo htmlspecialchars">
          <div>
                <h5 class="desc">Please Enter Your Information</h5>
             <input type="text" placeholder="DONATION AMOUNT" />
             <input  type="text" placeholder="FIRST NAME">
             <input  type="text" placeholder="LAST NAME">
             <input  type="text" placeholder="ADDRESS" />
             <input type="text" placeholder="CITY" />
             <input type="text" placeholder="STATE" />
             <input type="text" placeholder="ZIP" />
            <input  type="email" placeholder="E-MAIL">
            <input type="text" placeholder="PHONE" />
            <h5>How did you find Flower Spark / All Hallows Guild?</h5>
            <input type="text" placeholder="How did you find Flower Spark?"/>
          <div>
            <h5>Select payment method:</h5>
            <div class="pad-bot">
            <select name="Field106" class="field select medium" tabindex="11"> 
              <option value="First Choice">Credit Card/PayPal</option>
              <option value="Second Choice">Check/Money Order</option>
            </select>
            </div>
          </div>
            <button id="submit">
              <span class="state">Submit</span>
            </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

JS

```
swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success")
```

Comment: Please do not tag-spam.  Your question has absolutely nothing to do with the jQuery Validate plugin.  Edited.

Comment: Just a note, Java and Javascript are not the same thing. Maybe you already know this but thought I'd leave a comment to clarify.

Comment: What do you intend your form to do upon submission besides show the alert?

Comment: Sorry everyone for my ignorance with this, and thank you for correcting me. @Hydrothermal I intend for the alert to redirect to an interior page after 3 seconds if thats possible. And if the form is missing entries, a error alert instructing the user to make a correction. Again, I've never worked with JS before so I'm unsure how to impliment in HTML and JS

Comment: @Jennga Are you using jQuery?

Comment: @Hydrothermal yes 3.1.1

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#form').on('submit', function () {
  swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success")
});
```

OR

```
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function () {
  swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success")
});
```

Comment: but not going to show up since the form is going to submit an navigate away

Comment: I removed the form echo action to prevent the page from going somewhere else, is there something in the HTML I must include to make the sweet alert work? I'm sorry I'm still not getting this

Answer (score 0):

Add this JavaScript to your page, either after the form or wrapped in an onload handler:

```
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
    if(/* Validate form */) {
        swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success");
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.location = "redirect page";
        }, 3000);
    } else {
        //Display alert
    }

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Place whatever code you want to validate your form (e.g. check for missing fields) in the `if` statement, and whatever error message you want in the `else`.